# Java Quadratic Equation Class

Tags: java

I have yellow squiggly lines under my coeffA = in.nextDouble(); coeffB = in.nextDouble(); and coeffC = in.nextDouble(); in my tester class and can't figure out why? Also, when I run my tester class it always returns 0.0 and -0.0 I can't seem to get any calculations at all other than 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Directions:
I have to write a program that prints all real solutions to the quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c = 0. Read in a, b, c and use the quadratic formula. If the discriminant b^2 - 4ac is negative, display a message stating that there are no real solutions. Implement a class QuadraticEquation whose constructor receives the coefficients a, b, c of the quadratic equation. Supply methods getSolution1 and getSolution2 that get the solutions, using the quadratic formula, or 0 if no solution exists. The getSolution1 method should return the smaller of the two solutions. Supply a method boolean hasSolutions() that returns false if the discriminant is negative.

```
public class QuadraticEquation
{

double coeffA;
double coeffB;
double coeffC;
private boolean hasSolutions;
double discriminant;

public QuadraticEquation()
{
    coeffA = 0;
    coeffB = 0;
    coeffC = 0;
}

/**
Constructs a quadratic equation and get 2 solutions
@param coefficientA coefficient a of quadratic equation
@param coefficientB coefficient b of quadratic equation
@param coefficientC coefficient c of quadratic equation
*/
public QuadraticEquation(double coefficientA, double coefficientB, double coefficientC)
{
    coeffA = coefficientA;
    coeffB = coefficientB;
    coeffC = coefficientC;
    discriminant = (Math.pow(coeffB, 2) - 4 * coeffA * coeffC);
}

/**
 * Checks if there is a solution
 * @return true if there is a real solution
 */
public boolean hasSolutions()
{
if(discriminant < 0)
    hasSolutions = false;
else
    hasSolutions = true;
return hasSolutions;
}

/**
 * Returns the first solution to the quadratic equation
 * @return the first solution
*/
public double getSolution1()
{
    return (-coeffB + Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2 * coeffA);
}

/**
 * Returns the second solution to the quadratic equation
 * @return the second solution
*/
public double getSolution2()
{
    return (-coeffB - Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2 * coeffA);
}

}
```

Here is my tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 This program tests the QuadraticEquation class.
*/
 public class QuadraticEquationTester
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Please enter coefficient a: ");
    double coeffA = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter coefficient b: ");
    double coeffB = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter coefficient c: ");
    double coeffC = in.nextDouble();

    QuadraticEquation equation = new QuadraticEquation(0, 0, 0);

        if (equation.hasSolutions())
        System.out.println(equation.getSolution1());
        if (equation.hasSolutions());
        System.out.println(equation.getSolution2());
        System.exit(0);



  in.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: You know that this is Java and not VB.NET?

Comment: Also, it seems to work fine for me. I tried it with `new QuadraticEquation(1, -4, 2)`.

Comment: I know. I meant to put java. Accident. I am working with both java and VB right now, got mixed up a bit.

Comment: I can't enter my own numbers like you did above in the previous comment. I have to have user input their own set of coefficient numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have squiggly lines under `coeffA = in.nextDouble(); coeffB = in.nextDouble(); and coeffC = in.nextDouble();` because you assign to them but never use them.

You should change `QuadraticEquation equation = new QuadraticEquation(0, 0, 0);` to `QuadraticEquation equation = new QuadraticEquation(coeffA, coeffB, coeffC);`.

In the `getSolution` methods, the expressions have parenthesis in the wrong spots, which is causing calculations to be performed in the wrong order.

It should be

```
(-coeffB + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coeffA)
```

and

```
(-coeffB - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * coeffA)
```

Your if statements are also not correct. If it has real solutions, you want to print both solutions. If not, print that it has no real solutions:

```
if (equation.hasSolutions()) {
    System.out.println(equation.getSolution1());
    System.out.println(equation.getSolution2());
}
else {
    System.out.println("No real solutions.");
}
```

Comment: Everything calculates as no real solutions?? I think it did that prior and I changed it up to what I printed here.

Comment: You have to enter numbers such that the discriminant is >= 0.

Comment: I have entered positive and negative numbers, all negative and all postive. They are return no real solutions.

Comment: I have tested it with 1, 3, and 1, and it gives the correct solutions. Also, see my edit, because your expressions in the `getSolution` methods were not correct.

Comment: Okay. I entered 1, 3, 1 and I got some form of calculations so that is definitely a plus!

Comment: Is this correct?                                   -0.3819660112501051                                -2.618033988749895

Comment: Yes. You can check your answers by plugging the `x` values into the `ax^2 + bx + c = 0` equation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you create the instance of the class you enter 0, 0, 0. The class creation line should be as follows:

```
QuadraticFormula form = new 
QuadraticFormula(Coefficient A, b,..)
```

Sorry the formatting is weird I'm doing this on my phone. But basically put the coefficient that the user enters into the scanner input into the arguments.